# Question on geometry triangle and incenter

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle. Let B' and C' denotes respectively the reflection of B and C in the internal angle bisectors of angle A. How do I prove that the triangles ABC and AB'C' have same incenter.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The incentre of AB'C' is obtained by reflecting the incentre of ABC about the bisector.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/541127)

Comment: @Adolfo For pedagogical reasons, I felt in this instance that it would be more helpful to the OP to receive a hint, leaving room for them to discover some steps for themselves, than a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles $ABC$ and $AB'C'$ are symmetric over the angle bisector of $A$ and hence so do their incenters. Also since the incenters lies on the bisector they must be the same point.

Comment: plz help me with picture. Actually I didn't understand question.